# MySQL join field to result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a result set, and I need to join a related field from another table.

I have the following two tables.
The first table, 'components', keeps information about a component:

```
+----+-------+------------+-----------+
| id | name  | serial_num | model_num |
+----+-------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | comp1 | 0000       | AAAA      |
|  2 | comp2 | 0001       | AAAB      |
|  3 | comp1 | 0010       | AABA      |
|  4 | comp2 | 0011       | AABB      |
|  5 | comp3 | 0100       | ABAA      |
|  6 | comp1 | 0101       | AAAA      |
+----+-------+------------+-----------+
```

The second table, 'componentLog' tracks which system a component belongs to across time:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
| action_date | component | system  | action  | notes |
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2010-01-01  |         1 | CZMIL01 | added   | NULL  |
| 2010-02-25  |         1 | CZMIL01 | removed | NULL  |
| 2010-01-01  |         2 | CZMIL01 | added   | NULL  |
| 2010-02-03  |         2 | CZMIL01 | removed | NULL  |
| 2010-02-03  |         2 | CZMIL02 | added   | NULL  |
| 2010-01-14  |         3 | CZMIL02 | added   | NULL  |
| 2010-01-14  |         4 | CZMIL02 | added   | NULL  |
| 2010-02-03  |         4 | CZMIL02 | removed | NULL  |
| 2010-02-03  |         4 | CZMIL01 | added   | NULL  |
| 2010-01-14  |         5 | CZMIL02 | added   | NULL  |
| 2010-02-25  |         6 | CZMIL01 | added   | NULL  |
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+
```

I have a query that tells me which components are in a specified system on a specified date:

```
SELECT *
FROM components
WHERE id IN (
SELECT component
FROM componentLog
WHERE action_date <= '2010-02-25'
AND system = 'CZMIL01'
)
AND id NOT IN (
SELECT component
FROM componentLog
WHERE action_date <= '2010-02-25'
AND system = 'CZMIL01'
AND action = 'removed'
)
ORDER BY name;
```

This query provides the following result set:

```
+----+-------+------------+-----------+
| id | name  | serial_num | model_num |
+----+-------+------------+-----------+
|  6 | comp1 | 0101       | AAAA      |
|  4 | comp2 | 0011       | AABB      |
+----+-------+------------+-----------+
```

What I need is to join the 'action_date' field from the 'componentLog' table to this result set, thereby specifying when the component was added to the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `join` the tables with all the required conditions.

```
SELECT c.*,cl.action_date
FROM components c
JOIN componentLog cl on c.id = cl.component
WHERE action_date <= '2010-02-25'
AND system = 'CZMIL01'
AND action <> 'removed'
ORDER BY name;
```

If an component with atleast one `removed` action for a given system needs to be excluded from the result, use

```
select t.*, cl.action_date
from (
select * from components c
where not exists (select 1 from componentlog 
                  where component = c.id and action = 'removed' 
                  and system = 'CZMIL01' and action_date <= '2010-02-25')
) t
join componentLog cl on cl.component = t.id 
WHERE system = 'CZMIL01' and action_date <= '2010-02-25'
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

It looks like the second query is on the right track. However, a given component may be added and removed from a system numerous times on different equations. So I cannot exclude a component merely if it has a 'removed' action. The 'removed' action must be within the appropriate interval.

Comment: you can add `action_date < somedate` or `action_date > somedate` condition to `exists` to handle that. query modified to include that.

Comment: What if a component is removed from a system, and then at some later date added back to the system? The query would still exclude it from the result, even though it's back in the sytem.